# Which of the two methods to initialize the structure on the heap is better

Tags: c, performance

I thought of this problem when I was learning C,I thought of two ways to initialize the structure on the heap.

```c
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Point;

Point *test1(int x, int y, int z) {
    Point *point = (Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point));
    point->x = x;
    point->y = y;
    point->z = z;
    return point;
}

Point *test2(int x, int y, int z) {
    Point *point = (Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point));
    *point = (Point) {x, y, z};
    return point;
}
```

The writing in test1 is what I usually use, but the writing in test2 seems to be more convenient. But will test2 create extra objects?
Although the structure here has only 3 members, will the number of members affect the conclusion?

Comment: I don't think either of those methods would result in different instructions on a sensible compiler

Comment: There are two possible "betters" that I can think of.  Is it easier to read or does it execute faster.  To test the second you'd have to examine the output to see if the compiler made these functions different.  If so, run them millions or billions of times in a loop and compare execution time.

Comment: You should not write code like that in C++. In particular, you should not use `malloc`.

Comment: `Point* test(int x, int y, int z) {
    return new Point{x,y,z};
}` - to get away from `malloc` but I'd probably not use `new` either. Are you coding in C or C++?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different rules and different best-practices. Since you talk about C and the code is C I've removed the C++ tag

Answer (score 3):

Compilers will optimize both functions to identical code. [See for yourself on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/IjjxGu)

This is micro-optimizations. If you care about performance you first benchmark and profile then you optimize the hot spots.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do it, such as C99-style initialization:

```
Point *test3( int x, int y, int z ) {
    Point * const point = (Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point));
    if (point) { // Don't write through a NULL pointer!
      *point = { .x = x,
                 .y = y,
                 .z = z };
    }
    return point;
}
```

This has the advantage that it will still work if the members of `Point` are rearranged and extended.  It’s also useful for writing static single assignments.

I also tend to prefer `calloc()` to set all the uninitialized bits of the structure to zero.  It probably makes no difference, but if it did, that’s a really annoying Heisenbug to track down.